# jQuery replace / empty div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to empty anything inside inner if the screen width id smaller than 700px.

```
<body>
<div class="outter">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
       {{ content.something_1 }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (($(window).width() < 701)) {
    $(".inner").empty();
   }
  else {
    $(".inner").append( "{{ content.something_1 }}" );
  }
});
```

its not working.

Comment: you are doing greater than.. try `< 700`

Answer (score 2):

$(window).width() < 700 should be given.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try pure `CSS`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   .inner{
       dislay:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: its for drupal 8 -- trying to use a field on multiple regions on the same page --

Comment: this `CSS` is also work on all field on the page when width is less than `700px`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the this

> **$(window).width() should give you the screen width**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 701) {
    $(".inner").empty();
   } else {
    $(".inner").append( "{{ content.something_1 }}" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, you said that

> I want to empty anything inside inner **if the screen width id smaller
>   than 700px**.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (($(window).width() < 701)) {
    $(".inner").empty();
   }
  else {
    $(".inner").append( "{{ content.something_1 }}" );
  }
});
```

use `$(window)` if you need reference on the screen, using $(this) on your scenario just refers to the document

but what if the screen resizes?

you can use the event `resize`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 //do something when the screen is resized
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code up in a resize function to trigger it on viewport resize as well.

```
 <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="inner">
         {{ content.something_1 }}
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>



  $(document).ready(function() {
    var sWidth;
     $(window).resize(function(){
       sWidth = $(window).width();
       if (sWidth < 700) {
         $(".inner").empty();
       }
       else {
         $(".inner").append( "{{ content.something_1 }}" );
       }
     }).resize();      
  });
```